# What's the name of the surface and Is it a $C^2$ smooth surface?

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, surfaces

[image]

what's the name of the surface? Is it a $C^2$ smooth surface?
Its implicit equation is:
$(x−2)^2(x+2)^2+(y−2)^2(y+2)^2+(z−2)^2(z+2)^2+3(x^2y^2+x^2z^2+y^2z^2)+6xyz−10(x^2+y^2+z^2)+22=0$

Comment: Can you provide context?

Comment: If the answerer could also provide the general name for a similar object with $n$ holes I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Riemann surface of genus $3$?  That's just a topological classification though.

Comment: It's implicit function is $(x-2)^2(x+2)^2+(y-2)^2(y+2)^2+(z-2)^2(z+2)^2+3(x^2y^2+x^2z^2+y^2z^2)\\ +6xyz-10(x^2+y^2+z^2)+22=0$, Is it C^2 smooth?

Comment: In fairness, the linked question was not really answered. In fact it could not be answered, because the OP did not give us the equation of the surface. Now he has given the equation.

Comment: it is a genus three orientable surface

Comment: I marked as duplicate not because there was already an answer on the other question but to discourage OP from asking the same question twice.  If OP wants to add new info to the question, (s)he should do it to the one that was already asked.

Answer (score 2):

It looks to be a [Goursat surface](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GoursatsSurface.html), I have no software to be sure, if you have try to change the parameters.

But I'm not sure at 100%

[image]